# Map key to a script in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: bash, 18.04, xmodmap, xkb, xbindkeys

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 Bionic Beaver using an HP Pavilion laptop. My laptop has a key for toggling airplane mode. Using `xev`, I found out that it has keycode `255`. I've saved the following code at `/bin/airplane_mode` and set it as executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(nmcli r wifi)" = "enabled" ]
then
    nmcli r wifi off
else
    nmcli r wifi on
fi
```

Now, how can I set it up such that this file is run whenever I press that key? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you press that key in the "Set Shortcut" dialog you get when assigning a script to a hotkey in Settings - Keyboard?

Comment: @vanadium Nope. The key doesn't get registered.